# What is the output of this ML code?

Tags: ml

```
fun square(x:int) = x*x;

map (~, map (square, map (~, [1, 2, 3] )));
```

Would it just be the square of the three numbers (1, 4, 9)?
I tried running this on the SML of New Jersey but kept getting this error...

```
- fun square(x:int) = x*x;
val square = fn : int -> int
- map(~, map(square, map(~,[1,2,3])));
stdIn:3.11-3.35 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> 'Y
  operand:         ('X -> 'X) * int list
  in expression:
    map (~,1 :: 2 :: <exp> :: <exp>)
stdIn:3.4-3.36 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> 'Y
  operand:         (int -> int) * _
  in expression:
    map (square,map (~,<exp> :: <exp>))
stdIn:3.1-3.36 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z -> 'Y
  operand:         ('X -> 'X) * _
  in expression:
    map (~,map (square,map <exp>))
-
```

Answer (score 0):

As you found yourself, the only thing that this code will print is an error message. The reason for this is that `map` is a curried function and does not take its arguments in tuple form.

To fix this, you need to call `map` as a curried function (i.e. `map f xs` rather than `map (f, xs)`).

Comment: Thanks for the responce. I did that and it worked, I didn't get an error. I also tried "map  ~ [1,2,3]" and it worked, I didn't get an error. But I'm not getting an output or answer.

Comment: @user3582189 I'm not sure why you wouldn't get an answer. Did you forget to end with a `;` perhaps? Or maybe you have unclosed parentheses or something.